# What's this in Rprof report?

Tags: r

I use Rprof to profile the code and rewrite the slow part. However, I met a strange function in the report of Rprof:

```
> summaryRprof()
$by.self
                 self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"eval"               58.34    76.06      76.70    100.00
".C"                  8.38    10.93       8.38     10.93
"is.null"             3.42     4.46       3.42      4.46
...
```

I checked the output file of Rprof, and I saw a lot of

```
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source" 
"eval" "eval" "withVisible" "source"
```

So, what's this and how can I improve the code?

And the following is the main part of the code, it is sampling, and based on different group strategies to estimate a number. I used a nested list to do this. Rather awkward.

```
Rprof(file)
for (iter in 1 : 10) {
  tmp_samples <- sample(x = 1 : total_lost, size = sample_number, replace = TRUE)

  for (ele in tmp_samples) {
    cell_id <- (ele + 2) %/% 3

    for (i in 1 :  nrow(cluster)) {
      area <- cluster[i, cell_id]
      groups[[i]][[area]] <- c(groups[[i]][[area]], ele)
    }

    for (i in 1 : nrow(cluster))
      for (j in 1 : group_num[i]) 
        if (!is.null(groups[[i]][[j]]))
          .C("estimate", 
             as.integer(groups[[i]][[j]]), 
             as.integer(length(groups[[i]][[j]])),
             as.double(original[i, j]), as.double(smoothed[i, j]))
  }

}
Rprof(NULL)
```

Comment: we would need to see the code

Comment: They're the functions `source` uses.

Comment: @rawr the code is added. @Ulrich why `source` take so much time?